# Command Prompt doesn't return after launching Java application from Unix script

Tags: java, spring, unix, slf4j

I am running below command from a Unix script to launch my java/spring application. But the problem is, its starts logging some initial Spring logs on the screen itself not on the log file, though logs put in my java files would appear in only log file.                                                     Also the command prompt wouldn't return until I have to press Ctrl+C to get it returned .

```
JAVA=/someDirectory/java7_64/bin/java

${JAVA} -Xmx512m -Xms128m -cp "${ADirectory}/lib/*" -Duser.timezone=America/Chicago -DENVIRONMENT=$ENV -Djava.library.path=/somePath/java7_64/jre/lib:somePath/db2/db2clnt6/sqllib/lib SomePackage.SomeClass> ${LOG_DIR}/SomeLogFilename.log &
```

Comment: try using with debug, `-Xdebug`  `-Xrunjdwp`

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific about "some initial Spring logs"? Sometimes Spring logs out things just before the logging system is initialized.